# Access Azure Blob store from Sharepoint?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to access my azure blob storage account and display it from sharepoint?

I would like to give a customer access to some of the data that was generated for them that exists in a azure blob container I created for them.  I think this would be nicer in that I dont have to ask them to use cloudxplorer or some other thick client to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no built in way to do this. It would require some sort of custom development. At the very least some sort of JavaScript that could access the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx) for Azure BLOB storage and display it as a grid or list view. Of course you'd need to generate a “shared access signature” but all in all that could be relatively simple to build.